# React - Recorrer un .map, que devuelva un Select, y ese Select este asociado a otro Select

Tags: reactjs, select

Buen día!
Necesito ayuda
Tengo que hacer un formulario que tenga Materia y calificación. Pero las materias las voy trayendo de un .map, ya que depende de qué curso sea, traerá distintas materias. Lo que no estoy logrando es que por cada materia me traiga un select para elegir la calificación, así eso lo voy guardando en un objeto que tenga materia->calificación. Alguien se le ocurre como puedo hacerlo?

Comment: ¿Podrías colocar datos de ejemplo? Los arrays del map, la data a mostrar, etc.

Comment: Hola Basco, te invito a que leas las sección de cómo preguntar https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask De esta forma podremos ayudarte con tu problema

Answer (score 0):

espero que te sirva.

```js
import React, {useState} from 'react';

const categorias = [
 {
   "nombre" : "Audio",
   "articulos" : ["Monitor Led 27" , "Parlante Blurtooh", "Smart Tv 65"]
 },
 {
  "nombre" : "Ferreteria",
  "articulos" : ["Martillo pequeño" , "Taladro", "Serrucho"]
}

]

console.log("categorias", categorias)

function Menu() {

  const [idArticulos, setIdArticulos] = useState(-1);

  const handlerCargarArticulos = function (e){
  const opcion = e.target.value;
  console.log(opcion);
  
  setIdArticulos(opcion);

  }
  

    return (
        <div>
            <h3>Categorias</h3>
            <select name="categorias" id="selCategorias" onClick={handlerCargarArticulos}>
              <option value={-1}>Seleccione una opción: </option>
              {
                categorias.map((item, i)=>(
                  <option key={"categoria"+i} value={i}> {item.nombre}</option>
                ))
              }
            </select>
            <div></div>
            <h3>Articulos</h3>
            <select name="articulos" id="selarticulo">
              {
                idArticulos > -1 && 
                (
                  categorias[idArticulos].articulos.map((item,i)=>(
                    <option key={"articulo"+i} value="">{item}</option>
                  ))
                )
              }
            </select>

            

            
        </div>
    )
}

export default Menu
```